# Get async data with Angular resolver

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have resolver in my Angular 8 app

```
export class UserResolver implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) { }

  resolve() {
    this.authService.user.subscribe(user => {
      return user
    })
  }
}
```

But this is assign `null` to a router data, because `user` came with async function in my service (it came from the Subject). How can I make resolver to wait for data from my service to be returned, and not assign null value to a data?

Comment: Can you share your route configuration where you have used your `UserResolver`?

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1) Remove the `subscribe` and let the resolver handle the subscription.

2) Return the Observable, not the data.

Something like this:

```
export class UserResolver implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) { }

  resolve() {
    return this.authService.user;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Mine works, waiting and then returning the data. Mine looks like this:

```
constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<IProduct> {
        const id = +route.paramMap.get('id');
        return this.productService.getProduct(id);
    }
```

Notice that there is no subscribe and I'm returning the Observable returned from the http get operation.

My route configuration looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(ProductData),
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: 'products', component: ProductListComponent },
      {
        path: 'products/:id',
        component: ProductDetailComponent,
        resolve: { resolvedData: ProductResolver }
      },
      {
        path: 'products/:id/edit',
        component: ProductEditComponent,
        resolve: { resolvedData: ProductResolver }
      }
    ])
```

If you want working code, I have a more complex version of the above (more complex due to added exception handling) here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing/tree/master/APM-Final

Comment: It's never return data, if I change my code to this and page won't load.

Comment: Do you have it configured appropriately in the route configuration?

Comment: Yes, if I return just a string from resolver component receive it

Comment: I updated the above to include a link to a working resolver. If that doesn't help, consider building a stackbltiz that illustrates your issue and we can take a closer look.

Comment: Thank you very much for your sample project, it helped me "resolve" my problem.  :-)

Comment: How would you modify your code to entertain async/await request with your resolver? For example, I have userId in Storage. And I need that to perform the HTTP request. I can write `async resolve` and do a `const userId = this.authService.getUserId()`, but this is breaking the Routing. The Resolver no longer waits for the result of the HTTP request, rather it simply navigates away from the page to the destination and then waits for the HTTP request in the Resolver to resolve and then it fills the data. So, how to ensure that the Router waits for HTTP request to finish before navigating away?